# Query to support node to node search in neo4jrb

Tags: neo4jrb

I have this cypher query of

```
match p= (START:Task {name: 'Start'})-[*]->(finish:Task {name: 'C'})  return p
```

and would like to make the related active model query using neo4jrb.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information:

```
Neo4j::ActiveBase.query("match p= (START:Task {name: 'Start'})-[*]->(finish:Task {name: 'C'}) return p").pluck(:p)
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "related active model query", but if `Task` is a `ActiveNode` model you could also do

```
Task.query_as(:t).match("p=(t {name: 'Start'})-[*]->(:Task {name: 'C'})").pluck(:p)
```

But I think the first version is clearer. In both cases you're returning a `Neo4j::Core::Path` object.